# TB9051FTG Model Restrict DRC Error

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-layers, routing

So I picked up this model for TB9051FTG from UltraLibrarian via DigiKey, https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/TB9051FTG-EL/10123940

I am looking to route the VBAT inputs to the chip which supply power. What I don't understand is the restrict layer that seem to be included with the model.

[image]

You can see I have two pins on the top that have traces leading into what appears to be a restricted area. I have two options here

1. Connect the traces to the pins in the red restricted area which leads to a DRC failure.
2. Connect the traces up to the edge of the restricted area as close to the pins as possible, which leads to the airwires on the pins not being removed.

For context, I would like to connect those pins to a larger polygon as shown below.
[image]

Has anyone used this model? Is there any way I can connect to those pins without going  through the restricted area of the model?

Comment: I would try to find the recommended Footprint from Toshiba (it's not in the data sheet).

Comment: I'm struggling to find another model. I don't know why this model has a restrict all the way around the chip